# missing click event because blur event hiddes element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm implementing a "auto suggestion feature". This means:

- input element gets focus -> display suggestions
- input element looses focus -> hide suggestions

But if the user want to select an option via mouse, the click event is not firing because the blur event fires earlier and hides the clickable element.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/km8c0ft1/

Here is some example code:
js:

```
$('#test').blur(function() {
    $('#dropdown').css("display", "none");
});
$('#test').focus(function() {
    $('#dropdown').css("display", "inline");
});
```

html:

```
<input id="test" />
<input />
<input />

<ul id="dropdown" style="display: none">
    <li><a onclick="alert('option 1 selected')">option 1</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="alert('option 2 selected')">option 2</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="alert('option 3 selected')">option 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I understand the problem. But what is the best practice to solve this Problem?
I can implement the `setTimeout` Function to wait some ms until i hide the menu. But this feels like a hack and not like a clean solution.

Comment: this is just a example to show the problem. The hole feature is highly integrated and non of the existing plugins works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this : You can use `show()` or `hide()` instead of changing css values. Bind click event for anchor inside `li` to set selected value to text box. Bind click event for document and check if target is not input box to hide options.

```
$('#dropdown li a').click(function(e) {
    $('#test').val($(this).text());
    $('#dropdown').hide();
});

$(document).on("focus click keydown blur","*",function(e){
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
    if(keyCode == 9 || e.target.id!='test')
    $('#dropdown').hide();
});

$('#test').on("focus click",function(e) {
    $('#dropdown').show();
});
```

**[DEMO with Single Input](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/km8c0ft1/36/)** 
**[DEMO with Multiple Input](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/km8c0ft1/37/)**

Comment: `$('#dropdown').hide();` looks better than `$('#dropdown').css("display", "none");`, and `e.target.id != 'test'` will work a little faster than `!$(e.target).is("#test")`, but the problem is the same as in Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy's answer.

Comment: thx for your answers! But yes, the tab thing is really important, that's why i used the blur event.

Comment: please find the updated answer, now tab thing is also working

Comment: I don't know is it important situation or not, but updated answer will not work with pressing "tab" while having single `input`: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/km8c0ft1/31/).

Comment: Now this will work for single and multiple input for `tab` button, [single input](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/km8c0ft1/36/) and [multiple input](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/km8c0ft1/37/). Thanks @Regent, for pointing out these issues :)

Comment: @Regent, thanks and really appreciate your inputs :)

Comment: thx! this looks good. One addition: you don't need the keycode: `if(e.target.id!='test')` is enough